# Core Foundation in swift 3

Tags: swift3, core-foundation

I use CF classes in swift 3, and want to properly manage them. For example I have this line:

```
let phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
```

Normally when I used address book classes back in objc, whenever I call method that has copy in name, and I need to call `CFRelease()` after I finish using that object.

Now in swift i have 4 options to call

```
takeRetainedValue()
takeUnretainedValue()
retain()
autorelease()
```

But there is no `release()`. So if i want to use CF object in swift and then release it, which of these do I use?

Comment: maybe it is more reasonable to use the `Contact.framework` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, i need to support iOS8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `takeRetainedValue()` transfers ownership to ARC, consuming one retain. This takes care of your need to call `release`.